# Request.Form on input tag is empty

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, request.form

I am using Request.Form to get the text in the input field, however the value is always empty. I am trying to get the text value in the input tage and query my database. I am using a datepicker which writes the value to the input tag. I have tried writing to an asp Textbox, however the problem is after querying the database with the text in TextBox. When I choose a new date the Textbox does not update with new date value from datepicker. That is why I am using input tag. The problem here is that Request.Form["input"] always gets an empty string.

.aspx file

```
<form runat="server" method="post">      
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="insert into db" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

script.js

```
var picker = new Pikaday(
    {
        field: document.getElementById('input'),
        trigger: document.getElementById('scheduleDate'),
        minDate: new Date(Date.now()),
        disableDayFn: function (date) {
            // Disable Monday
            var allDates = date.getDate();
            return date.getDay() === 6 || date.getDay() === 0;
                //block out dates that are fully booked.
        },
        toString(date, format) { // using moment.js
            return moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        },

    });
```

cs file

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string date = Request.Form["input"];
        
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; Integrated Security = True"))
        {
            //string selectquery = "SELECT * FROM Events";
            string sqlquery = "INSERT INTO [Events] (start_date, end_date) VALUES ('" + date + "', '" + date + "')";
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, connection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();

        }

    }
```

Comment: There is no control with the "input" id/name inside your form tag.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need (or want) to use request.form.

Just drop your controls into the page. And then they can be freely used throuhout your code. So, say this markup:

```
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="insert into db" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

</ContentTemplate>
```

Now, in your code?

```
DateTime MyDate = DateTime.Parse(TextBox2.Text);

string MyTextBox1Text = TextBox1.Text;
```

So, in your case, you looking to do this:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; Integrated Security = True"))
{
    string sqlquery = "INSERT INTO [Events] (start_date, end_date) VALUES (@MyDate,@MyDate)";
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, conn))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@MyDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = TextBox1.Text;
        conn.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```